# Bash command to find files based on a list of filenames

Tags: bash, terminal

Using terminal on a mac, I have this bash command from my previous research that works great.

It searches only one level of a directory and moves all files (matching a text list of filenames) depositing them into a new directory.

```
while read filename; do mv DIR/${filename}.jpg NEWDIR/; done < filenamelist.txt
```

I now need it to able to search through any subfolders within DIR as well. The subfolders will all have random names usually. 
I don't think the MV move command has any recursive option, and haven't been able to find any other specific solutions. Should I be using a proper shell script instead of just one command line?

I'm still learning, would really appreciate any pointers! Thanks for reading.

Comment: What happens if filenames are the same on different directories?Aka filename collision.

Comment: Good question! I haven't encountered that yet, as only being able to search in one level of the directory means there couldn't be any duplicate filenames anyway. 
And the NEWDIR I use to move them to is empty.

But this could definitely be a problem in searching subfolders as we might have a few .jpgs with the same names. If it could auto-resolve and grab all the duplicates anyway that would be fine.

Comment: Could you clarify: do you want `DIR/path/to/filename => NEWDIR/path/to/filename` or do you want `DIR/path/to/filename => NEWDIR/filename`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` to search in subfolders:

```
while read filename; do find DIR/ -name "${filename}.jpg" -exec mv "{}" NEWDIR/ \; ; done < filenamelist.txt
```

You can use the `mv` options `-f` to force overwrite or `-n` to not overwrite existing files.